# How to mock Pinia and vue-i18n at the same time?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I'm using Vue 3's Composition API like so:

store.ts

```js
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useStore = defineStore('store', () => {
  const isLoading: Ref<boolean> = ref(true);

  function init() {
    isLoading.value = true;
    setTimeout(() => (isLoading.value = false), 3000);
  }

  return {
    init,
    isLoading,
  };
});
```

Component.vue

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { useStore } from './store';

const { t } = useI18n();
const store = useStore();
const { isLoading } = storeToRefs(store);
</script>

<template>
  <wb-button @click="store.init()">{{ t('init') }}</wb-button>
  <p>Loading: {{ isLoading ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</p>
</template>
```

That all works fine and dandy but when I try to test stuff it gets messy. So far I have mocked vue-i18n globally like this:

testSetup.ts

```js
import { vi } from 'vitest';

vi.mock('vue-i18n', () => ({
  useI18n: () => ({
    t: (key: string) => key,
    d: (key: string) => key,
  }),
}));
```

However, that works only until I try mocking the store simultaneously like this:

Component.test.ts

```js
import { it, expect, vi } from 'vitest';
import { mount} from '@vue/test-utils';
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing';
import Component from './Component.vue';

const options = {
  global: {
    plugins: [
      createTestingPinia({
        createSpy: vi.fn(),
        initialState: {
          items: [],
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};

it('works', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Component, options);
  expect(wrapper.findComponent(Component)).toBeTruthy();
});
```

As soon as I add the change to the plugin configuration to enable the Pinia mock, the vue-i18n mock stops working and throws the old familiar `TypeError: $setup.t is not a function`. I also tried to use `config.global.mocks` and `config.global.plugins` to mock vue-i18n but all of these solutions stop working as soon as I add Pinia mocking to the tests. I think the reason is that the `config.global` object is somehow reset by `@pinia/testing` but I don't know how to prevent this behavior.

package.json

```
"@pinia/testing": "0.0.16",
"@types/jsdom": "21.1.1",
"@types/node": "18.16.2",
"@vue/test-utils": "2.3.2",
"jsdom": "21.1.1"
"typescript": "~4.8.4",
"vite": "4.3.3",
"vitest": "0.30.1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `createSpy` property expects a function but a call was supplied. Change `vi.fn()` to `vi.fn` and everything works as expected.

```
createTestingPinia({
  createSpy: vi.fn, <--
  ...
})
```

Source: https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html#specifying-the-createspy-function

Comment: Good find. Are you suggesting `createI18n()` plugin provided to mount function is not necessary? Actually, it's not, because you're mocking the entire module. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the mounted component doesn't have a `t` function, because you're not adding VueI18n as a plugin to mounting options:

```
import { it, expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import Component from './Component.vue'
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const options = {
  global: {
    plugins: [
      createPinia(),
      createI18n({
        legacy: false,
        locale: 'en-US',
        messages: {
          'en-US': {
            init: 'Initialize'
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  }
}

it('does work', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Component, options)
  expect(wrapper.findComponent(Component)).toBeTruthy()
})
```

In more detail, `global.plugins` expects a Vue plugins array (objects or class instances with a `install()` function) and does the same thing as `app.use(somePlugin)`.
You need to place there all plugins on which the tested component (and descendants, when not shallow-mounting) relies on. This is because each component is tested in isolation (that's why they're called unit tests), they're not mounted inside the actual app.

In short, you're seeing the same behavior you would see if you tried to use `VueI18n` without adding `.use(VueI18n)` to the `app`.

---

To reduce boilerplate in test files, export a `mountingOptions` from `test.utils.ts`:

```js
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

export const mountingOptions = {
  global: {
    plugins: [
      createPinia(),
      createI18n({
        legacy: false,
        locale: 'en-US',
        messages: {
          'en-US': {
            init: 'Initialize'
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Typically, `mountingOptions` should contain all plugins you've added to `app`, in `main`.

Then, in any test:

```
import { mountingOptions } from '../test.utils'
//...
const wrapper = mount(Component, mountingOptions)
```

Comment: Getting the same error: `[Vue warn]: A plugin must either be a function or an object with an "install" function. TypeError: $setup.t is not a function`

Comment: In that case, the export from 'vue-I18n' is not the plugin, in the version you're using. I assumed you're using the [latest version](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/installation.html). Bottom line is: you should provide the plugin to the test ***the same way you're providing it to the app, in main***.

Comment: In your case: `createI18n({ legacy: false, ... })`. That function returns an object which has an `install()` function, which can be used by `app.use()` and inside the `global.plugins` array of your test.

Comment: Actually, you ***are*** using the latest version. It's the documentation that seems obsolete. If you use the link to docs I placed above, you'll notice the documented way of using the plugin is to place the default export of the package inside `.use()` function. So they changed the API in `v9`.

Comment: I updated my answer for `v9`. I hope I've also made the principle behind the code clear, so you can figure out how to provide other plugins to your tests, if/when needed.

Comment: I still get the same error (see updated repo). Also, why can't I just mock the imports? The component just uses the t-function which is imported, right?

Comment: You can mock it. But the component has to use it before you can mock it. If you want it mocked you need to provide the plugin to the mount ***and*** the mock in test setup.

Comment: hm okay, I'm fine with either but currently both ways aren't working unfortunately :/

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at the repo you added later today. Out of principle, repo links are discouraged because they tend to become outdated after the question is answered and a fix is implemented in the project. The recommended solution is to provide a [mcve] (codesandbox.io or similar).

Comment: You're right! I added a sandbox link to the question because it is too long for a comment

Comment: I wasn't able to make `useTestingPinia()` work and I don't fully understand why. But it works fine with a proper store (e.g: pass `createPinia()` to the test's plugins). [Here it is](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/leonheess/temp/csb-oulucx/draft/floral-thunder?file=/src/components/__tests__/Component.spec.ts). If you want to get to the bottom of why `createTestingPinia()` doesn't work, perhaps you should ask on `pinia`'s repo. I never had to mock a store since I started using pinia, I just export a `pinia = createPinia()` + all stores from `./store` folder.

Comment: When I try to use `useTestingPinia()` in your example, I get a `store.init` is not a function error. For obvious reasons, I updated the answer with code that actually works.